# How to match multiple values in a WHERE clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to show fk in multiple table but I can show only one table.

```
SELECT 
   'ALTER TABLE ['+sch.name+'].['+referencingTable.Name+'] DROP CONSTRAINT ['+foreignKey.name+']' 'DropCommand'
FROM sys.foreign_key_columns fk
    JOIN sys.tables referencingTable ON fk.parent_object_id = referencingTable.object_id
    JOIN sys.schemas sch ON referencingTable.schema_id = sch.schema_id
    JOIN sys.objects foreignKey ON foreignKey.object_id = fk.constraint_object_id
    JOIN sys.tables referencedTable ON fk.referenced_object_id = referencedTable.object_id
WHERE referencedTable.name = 'branch_supplier'
```

I tried to use this for multiple table and it seem like it didn't work.

```
DECLARE @test NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT TABLE_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' 
    AND TABLE_CATALOG='assign2'
    AND TABLE_NAME IN ('employee', 'branch', 'branch_supplier')' 

SELECT 
   'ALTER TABLE ['+sch.name+'].['+referencingTable.Name+'] DROP CONSTRAINT ['+foreignKey.name+']' 'DropCommand'
FROM sys.foreign_key_columns fk
    JOIN sys.tables referencingTable ON fk.parent_object_id = referencingTable.object_id
    JOIN sys.schemas sch ON referencingTable.schema_id = sch.schema_id
    JOIN sys.objects foreignKey ON foreignKey.object_id = fk.constraint_object_id
    JOIN sys.tables referencedTable ON fk.referenced_object_id = referencedTable.object_id
WHERE referencedTable.name = @test
```

Comment: Please add a tag for the DBMS implementation (e.g. PostgreSQL, Oracle, MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, etc.) being used

Comment: You're filtering the results to only match a single table name `WHERE referencedTable.name = @test`. If you want different results, use a different WHERE condition. If you want to match multiple strings use an `IN (..)` clause. `WHERE referencedTable.name IN ('employee', 'branch', 'branch_supplier')`